# Can I open a resourcepath with File.Open in C#

Tags: c#, resources, filestream

I try to open a resourcefile in C# using this line, I can't see why this not working. I have tried to use build action = "embedded resource" and "none". 
I have tried all ways of copy to output directory. 
Do I need some special way of opening up resourcefiles to fileStream with c#?

```
    public bool openFileStream()
    {
        FileStream mFileStream;
        String[] s=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        String mFilename =null;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length;i++ )
        {
            s[i] = s[i].Replace(".", "\\");

            if (s[i].Contains("sju_tre_g_i"))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Substring(0, s[i].Length - 4);
                s[i] = s[i] + ".wav";
                mFilename = s[i];

            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i + "___Outputname:" + mFilename);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mFilename);
        try{
            mFileStream = File.Open(mFilename,FileMode.Open );
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

EDIT not duplicate
In the duplicate there is just to open a text-file. It is the adress to use to FileStream mFileStream; mFileStream=File.Open("WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\‌​sju_tre_g_i.wav",Fil‌​eMode.Open );

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error or an exception or are you just not getting the result you expect?

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: In the duplicate there is just to open a text-file. It is the adress to use to FileStream mFileStream; mFileStream=File.Open("WindowsFormsApplication2\\Resources\\sju_tre_g_i.wav",FileMode.Open );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open an wav file from the resouces you can do this.

```
using (var steam = Properties.Resources.sju_tre_g_i)
{
     // do something       
}
```

Just be aware that this isn't a `FileStream` but an `UnmanagedMemoryStream`. (But as the ressource library is loaded into memory anyway it shouldn't make a difference?)

---

If you want to ensure a directory exists and you want to open a file when it exists and create it when it doesn't you can do the following.

```
var path = @"C:\mypath\myfile.txt";
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
     // do something            
}
```

You can also use an relative path if you like.

Comment: But the file is in the resourcefolder in my project. If it can't be found then there is something wrong with how I adress it. It is the same way (File.Open) as I already use.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the full code for the method

Comment: I got to old version for nameof, gonna look for alternative first and see

Comment: @bajenmicke I got rid of `nameof`. It wasnt nessesary anyway.

Comment: Thank you NtFreX. With unmanagedMemoryStream instead of FileStream it works perfect